# Is the canonical isomorphism to double dual unique?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space. There is a canonical isomorphism $\varphi:V\rightarrow V^{**}$.

Is $\varphi$ unique? Namely, when $\psi:V\rightarrow V^{**}$ is another isomorphism that is defined independently of the choice of basis, do $\varphi$ and $\psi$ coincide?

Comment: What makes the canonical isomorphism canonical is more than its independence of a choice of basis. There is probably some category theory way to describe the true canonicalness of the definition. If I knew it I'd post an answer rather than a comment. I hope someone knowledgeable will.

Comment: If you want $\varphi_V$ to commute with linear maps, then it is unique up to multiplication by a scalar. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/730995/660 - @EthanBolker

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard Indeed. Please post that as an answer. I don't think the link is a duplicate.since it's much more complex.

Answer (score 2):

If the space $V$ has any nontrivial automorphism $\alpha$, then the composition $\psi=\varphi\circ\alpha$ is another isomorphism that is not identical to $\varphi$. Any vector space with dimension $>1$ has a non-trivial automorphism obtained by permuting basis elements. Therefore, in these cases, the canonical isomorphism to the double-dual is not unique.

Comment: True - but seem my comment on the question.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is negative. Over field $k \neq \mathbb{F}_2$, take $c \in k \setminus \{0, 1\}$, and $\psi = c \cdot \varphi$.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit.** Here is an elementary argument.

Let $\varphi_V:V\to V^{**}$ be the canonical morphism and let $\psi_V:V\to V^{**}$ be another functorial morphism.

Let's insist one the fact that $\varphi_V$ and $\psi_V$ depend functorially on the vector space $V$.

There is a scalar $\lambda$ in the ground field $K$ such that $\psi_K=\lambda\varphi_K$.

We claim that we have $\psi_V=\lambda\varphi_V$ for all $V$.

All the maps below are $K$-linear.

Given $v:K\to V$, it suffices to show $\psi_V(v(1))=\lambda\varphi_V(v(1))$.

But we have 
$$
\psi_V(v(1))=v^{**}(\psi_K(1))=\lambda v^{**}(\varphi_K(1))=\lambda \varphi_V(v(1)).
$$ 
**End of the edit.**

The answer to your question is contained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2087805/660).

End of the answer. Please do **not** read the text below.

[I tried to post the first sentence above as an answer, but the software insisted on posting it as a comment, so I tried to add some filler...]

Comment: A good way to add more characters would be to explain *how* the answer to this question is contained in the linked answer.

Comment: @GTonyJacobs - Done.

Comment: Sorry to ask a question on a year old answer, but why is the last equality in your post correct? Why is it true that the functors defined by $\psi_V$ and $\phi_V$ take $v$ to $v^{**}$?

Comment: @Serg - $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are not functors, but natural transformations. More precisely they are natural transformations from the identity functor $V\mapsto V$ to the double dual functor $V\mapsto V^{**}$. The equality $v^{**}\circ\varphi_K=\varphi_V\circ v$ follows from the assumption that $\varphi$ is a natural transformation.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard. I see. It's just that in my understanding a canonical isomorphism is an isomorphism which can be extended to a functor. Are there any other endofunctors of the category of finite dimensional vector spaces which maps $V$ to $V^{**}$?

Comment: @Serg - If $\lambda$ is a nonzero scalar, then $\lambda$ times the canonical isomorphism can be extended to a functor, but it's not called "the canonical isomorphism". I believe the answer to you question is yes, but I'm not sure. Note that the question is equivalent to: Are there endofunctors of the category of finite dimensional vector spaces which maps $V$ to $V$ and which are not the identity functor? (The point is that functors must also be defined on morphisms, not only on objects.)